# How to create a rectangle in moderncv

Tags: boxes, moderncv

I would like to create a rectangle under my personal info in order to fill it with my strenght, key achivements, etc. But I have no idea how to do it.
Actually I have something like this :
[image]
and I would like something like this :
[image]

Do you have any idea how to do it ?

Here is a minimal example :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,verdana]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[burgundy]{classic}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\familyname{}
\address{}    
\email{}                      
\mobile{}


\begin{document}


\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Thank you

Comment: I like the `tcolorbox` package. However, as to *where* that box would go in the `.tex` file is hard to say when you don't provide the `.tex` file. (Note: please provide a minimal `.tex` file, not the whole CV.)

Comment: you can do this for example with `\quote{%
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
framed text long as you need it
\end{minipage}}
some extra text
\end{minipage}}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution.

```
\quote{% 
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} \centering\fbox{%
 \begin{minipage}{\textwidth} framed text long as you need it \end{minipage}} some extra text \end{minipage}}
```